# jQuery UI Draggable Limit (Pixels)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a JSFiddle ([Link to it](http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/rFSHm/2/)) where I have a draggable rectangle (100*200px), it also has a `padding-bottom:20px;` and a `margin-top:-200px;`. I just want to show the padding-bottom and to have a limit of scrolling, like using delimeter but due to the complete code, I can't wrap this into another DIV, is there any way to set the `draggable()` and keep the div into its original size?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable">
<ul>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
    <li>One item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
​#draggable{
     width:300px; 
     height:200px; 
     background:#333; 
     line-height:20px; 
     padding-bottom:20px; 
     font-size:14px;
     color: #fff; 
     margin-top:-200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#draggable').live('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).draggable({
                    axis: "y",
                    scroll: false   
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want.
Something like that?
http://jsfiddle.net/jdqUs/